# ffmpegのインストールについて

Tags: centos, ffmpeg

ffmpegでmp4からhlsの変換を行うためにインストールしたのですが `Unknown encoder 'libfdk_aac'` のエラーが出てしまいます。
何が原因でしょうか？
OSはCentOS6.6です
よろしくお願いします。

1. 下記サイトに従ってインストール

   http://qiita.com/RyoIkarashi/items/48419f71f15f97c46123

   - yasmは1.3.0のバージョンで行いました
   - libxvid(1.3.3）のインストールを追加しました
   - fdk-aac(0.1.4)のインストールを追加しました
2. サーバにinput.mp4を配置して下記コマンドを実行

   ```
   ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 800k -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -flags +loop-global_header -map 0 -bsf h264_mp4toannexb -f segment -segment_format mpegts -segment_time 10 -segment_list output.m3u8 stream%04d.ts
   ```
3. Unknown encoder 'libfdk_aac'が表示されて正常に実行できません。1でfdk-aacを入れても変わりません。

   実行結果詳細

   ```
   ffmpeg version N-72570-gf104970 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
     built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)
     configuration: --prefix=/usr/local --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-shared --enable-libfaac --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid
     libavutil      54. 26.101 / 54. 26.101
     libavcodec     56. 41.101 / 56. 41.101
     libavformat    56. 34.100 / 56. 34.100
     libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
     libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
     libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
     libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
     libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
   Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
     Metadata:
       major_brand     : mp42
       minor_version   : 0
       compatible_brands: mp42mp41
       creation_time   : 2015-04-06 03:26:23
     Duration: 00:00:06.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1072 kb/s
       Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 904 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29970 tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
       Metadata:
         creation_time   : 2015-04-06 03:26:23
         handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Video Media Handler
         encoder         : AVC Coding
       Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 157 kb/s (default)
       Metadata:
         creation_time   : 2015-04-06 03:26:23
         handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
   Unknown encoder 'libfdk_aac'
   ```

Comment: エンコーダー名が異なる可能性はないでしょうか?
'libfdk_aac'ではなく、'fdk_aac'と指定する必要があるとか。
`$ ffmpeg -formats`
で確認できるみたいです。

参考にしたページ→
[http://www.cagylogic.com/archives/2014/06/21134514.php]
[http://yoshifumi.hateblo.jp/entry/20080119/p1]

Comment: ありがとうございます。
（リンクが切れているようです。）
ffmpeg -formatsを実行
 D  aac             raw ADTS AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
と表示
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 800k -acodec aac  -b:a 128k -flags +loop-global_header -map 0 -bsf h264_mp4toannexb -f segment -segment_format mpegts -segment_time 10 -segment_list output.m3u8 stream%04d.t
で実行
-strict -2をつけろとエラー
下記で再実行
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 800k -acodec aac -strict -2 -b:a 128k -flags +loop-global_header -map 0 -bsf h264_mp4toannexb -f segment -segment_format mpegts -segment_time 10 -segment_list output.m3u8 stream%04d.ts

Comment: すいません。リンクの指定の仕方間違っていました。
[一つ目](http://www.cagylogic.com/archives/2014/06/21134514.php)、[二つ目](http://yoshifumi.hateblo.jp/entry/20080119/p1)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ところで
回答のほうに書いて頂ければ承認いたします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。回答の方に転記しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エンコーダー名が異なる可能性はないでしょうか? 'libfdk_aac'ではなく、'fdk_aac'と指定する必要があるとか。`$ ffmpeg -formats`で確認できるみたいです。

参考にしたページ
http://cagylogic.com/archives/2014/06/21134514.php
http://yoshifumi.hateblo.jp/entry/20080119/p1